# Como colocar un punto en una posición específica de un string python

Tags: python, arcgis

Tengo una base de datos donde tengo columnas latitud y longitud con formato erróneo que preciso corregir para poder georreferenciar.
La estructura de las columnas es la siguiente:

| Lat | Long |
| --- | --- |
| -314193332 | -6419125129999990 |
| -313147283 | -641708031 |

y el formato que yo deseo lograr para que corresponda al formato de coordenadas es el siguiente:

| Lat | Long |
| --- | --- |
| -31.4193332 | -64.19125129999990 |
| -31.3147283 | -64.1708031 |

Para ello debería poder agregar un "." en la tercera posición de cada valor de la columna pero no me doy cuenta como podría hacerlo. Saludos y gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué pasa con las latitudes/longitudes menores a 10°? Por ejemplo, "532000 N 0 W"

Comment: Dado que estoy usando el sistema de coordenadas de wgs 84 en la ciudad de córdoba, argentina específicamente los valores siempre serían -31.xxx , -64.xxxx pero es una buena pregunta!

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa para poner un punto en un lugar específico de un número podría ser dividir por una potencia de 10, según la longitud de la cadena de texto.

```py
def punto(numero, posición):
    """ Coloca un punto decimal en la posición indicada.
        de un número entero.

        :param numero: Número entero a convertir.
        :param posición: Numero que indica la posición deseada.

        :return float: Número con punto decimal en la posición indicada.
    """
    if isinstance(numero, int):
        numero = str(numero)
    if not isinstance(posición, int):
        posición = int(posición)
    
    divisor = 10 ** (len(numero) - (int(posición) + 1))
    return int(numero) / divisor
```

Ejemplo para poner el punto en la segunda posición.

```py
In [2]: numbers = [-314193332, "-6419125129999990", -313147283, "-641708031"]
   ...: for number in numbers:
   ...:     print(punto(number, 2))
-31.4193332
-64.1912512999999
-31.3147283
-64.1708031
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta función inserta un "." en la posición indicada, contando sólo los digitos:

```
def insert(cadena, posicion):
    if cadena[0].isdigit():
        posicion -= 1

    return cadena[:posicion] + "." + cadena[posicion:]
```

Es tan simple como partir la cadena en la posición dada y luego reunir los trozos insertando un "." entremedio.

La posición debe ajustarse considerando que puede haber un "-" delante del número.

#### Demo

```
def insert(cadena, posicion):
    if cadena[0].isdigit():
        posicion -= 1

    return cadena[:posicion] + "." + cadena[posicion:]

tests = ["-314193332", "-641708031", "314193332", "641708031"]
for test in tests:
    print(test, insert(test, 3))
```

produce:

```
-314193332 -31.4193332
-641708031 -64.1708031
314193332 31.4193332
641708031 64.1708031

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Excelente, y si el valor de la columna fuera int en vez de string habría una forma más facil de hacerlo? Gracias

Comment: @bonafepedro podés convertir la columna en cadena.

Answer (score 0):

Si no tenes ganas de convertir la columna a cadena, podemos hacer algunas cuentas matematicas para lograrlo.

#### Razonamiento matematico

La formula para saber cuantas cifras enteras tiene un numero es:

```
floor(log(abs(numero))) + 1
```

Donde floor significa "redondear hacia abajo", log es el logaritmo de base 10 (es decir, a que número hay que elevar 10 para obtener numero) y abs es la función matematica modulo (hace positivo al numero). El resultado de esa cuenta da el número de cifras menos 1, por lo que le tenemos que sumar 1.

Y la formula para correr el punto decimal a la izquierda es:

```
numero / 10 ** veces a correr
```

Nosotros queremos correr el punto a

```
numero cifras - 2
```

Haciendo las sustituciones adecuadas

```
numero / 10 ** (floor(log(abs(numero))) + 1 - 2)
numero / 10 ** (floor(log(abs(numero))) - 1)
```

#### Función en Python

> Nota: No funciona bien con numeros que tienen dos cifras o menos

Usando la librería math para calcular con presición el logaritmo, podemos diseñar una función así:

**Código**

```
import math

def correr_punto(num):
    return num / 10 ** (math.floor(math.log10(math.fabs(num))) - 1)

print(correr_punto(6419125129999990))
print(correr_punto(1), "resultado incorrecto, ya que tiene dos cifras o menos")
```

**produce**

```
-64.1912512999999
10.0 resultado incorrecto, ya que tiene dos cifras o menos
```

> Nota final. Esta cuenta devuelve un flotante. El cual, al usar en el fondo base 2, no funciona bien con nuestra base 10. Quizá quieras usar el modulo decimal (a costo de velocidad) para solucionar eso si es que te es importante.